# Bamboo task to update properties file before maven build

Tags: shell, spring-boot, bamboo

I am using spring-boot and would like to update the `application.properties` file in the `/src/main/resources` folder as a task within a manual build plan. As the service can be installed on premise at the customer, I want to build the jar for each customer, where I can provide variables (e.g. spring.data.mongodb.* properties) to be injected/overridden before the maven build.

I found the [inject](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210847/inject-variables-plugin-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview) plugin, but this adds a prefix before the variables, which in this case wont work as the DB connection is done automatically with spring.

Is there another plugin I didn't find which could do the trick, or is there an easy way to script something like this (please provide an example as I am not very familiar with shell scripts)?

Comment: The whole idea of re-building the app individually for each customer is wrong according to the [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config). Instead you should store and read customer specific config from the environment.

Comment: @Boris fair point, though we are also thinking of disabling certain features depending on the customer license and if this isn't within the code it can easily be "hacked". But for now it could make sense to provide a customer specific config file in the launch script.

Comment: I see. Then how about binding the app to a given customer through a "hardware fingerprint"? It would include several physical server parameters that can collectively identify the server and prevent piracy.